# Did Hanuman undergo a surgery after he pierced his chest to show that Lord Ram was inside him?

Tags: ramayana, hanuman

We all know that, when Sita Devi gave Hanuman a pearl necklace, Hanuman said that its of no use to him as Lord Ram is not inside of it.

So when asked whether Lord Ram is inside him, Hanuman torn his chest apart to show that Lord Ram and Sita devi were inside him.

But what happened after this incident? What happened to Hanuman? Did he live the rest of his life  with a torn chest or did he undergo some surgery to fix it?

I believe all these incidents took place in real, it is not meant to disrespect Hanuman or Lord Ram but to know the real incident fully, so please answer it correctly.

Comment: Hanuman didn't pierce his chest.  Check [Why is lord Hanuman portrayed as splitting his chest and showing that lord Rama is within it?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/450/3500)

Comment: "This question does not appear to be about Hindu religion, within the scope defined in the help center." .. What???

Answer (score 4):

Usually bodies of Gods are having super human capabilities. Apart from the fact you mentioned in your question, as per the legend book, [Ram Charit Manas,  written by Tulsidas.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7T0zBCVuV7cR055dEFfNFRNQ28/view)

> "Even as Surasa expanded her jaws Hanuman manifested a form twice as
>   large as her mouth.When she further expanded her mouth eight hundred
>   miles wide, Hanuman assumed a very minute form"
>
> **Sundar Kanda, page 820, sloka 5**

So Hanuman's body was not a normal human body which we can think of and make interpretations with our senses. These are kind of mystical powers which we ordinary mortals don't have. That's why they are given the status of God in mythology.

So in my opinion Hanuman ji did not need any surgery, he showed by his powers that only lord lives in his heart and to prove his point he had to open his chest.

In our present age there has been a great saint who with the help of Hanuman ji was able to do miracles though he never claimed himself to do any thing and mentioned always it is Hanuman ji who is doing all this. He is known as Neem Karoli Baba you may read more about him on google for a starting I am giving below a couple of links.

[Neem Karoli Baba](http://%20neemkarolibaba.blogspot.in/2007/04/chamatkari-baba-babajis-miracles-were.html)

[www.maharajji.com/Miracle-of-Love/address-to-maharajji-s-photo.html](http://www.maharajji.com/Miracle-of-Love/address-to-maharajji-s-photo.html)

Many ascetics in Himalaya are able to develop such powers so it is no wonder that Hanuman ji had the power to heal himself.

To have an understanding of how siddhi's work is important to understand the answer 
you may consider reading a couple of books to understand
1) www.amazon.com/Autobiography-Self-Realization-Fellowship-Paramahansa-Yogananda/dp/0876120796/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1503311391&sr=1-1&keywords=autobiography+of+a+yogi

2) www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=living+with+himalayan+masters+&rh=n%3A283155%2Ck%3Aliving+with+himalayan+masters+

an understanding of Kriya yog  googling about Kriya Baba and Kriya yog may act as starting point.

Comment: That sounds unrealistic. Hindu scriptures and texts seems to be scientifically inclined many times rather than a mythology. So I'm not accepting with you.

Comment: what is unrealistic

Comment: No @KawinM he must be right. Do u know that Hanuman has the 8 siddhis among which by one he can become as big as he wants and by another he can become as small as he wants? So if u consider Hanuman an ordinary being like us (who will need surgery to heal wounds) how were those acts of his can be scientifically validated? We of course can't make ourselves big or small at our wishes.

Comment: yes this is what I wanted to say by mentioning the point that Hanuman had enlarged his body magnificently., the book which  I have mentioned was written by a divine order from Lord Shiva to Tulsidas
http://www.speakingtree.in/allslides/truth-behind-lord-shivas-signature-satyam-shivam-sundaram-unveiled/lord-rama-guarding-ramcharitmanas
the authenticity of this book which I quoted was very much questioned in those time when it was written, however Lord himself had to give proof in those times and this fact is very widely accepted ,a lot of examination of this book and author was done

Comment: you may read this link to know more about tulsidas and how the book was written Tulsidas was in the era of Akbar 11 February 1556 – 27 October 1605, I am more than welcome to your comments,critics questions answer  comment to my capacity until it exhausts my knowledge

Comment: "When she further expanded her mouth eight hundred miles wide". Her 800 miles = 1120 kms. Mouth is just maybe around 1% of total body length. So by doing math, the whole length surasa at that time maybe 112,000 kms which is 1/3 of the distance from earth to moon. At such altitude the organism cant breath and not only hanuman, even moon seems to be minute form compared to that thing.

Comment: If an organism has a length of 112,000 kms its body weight will be rougly equal to 67 lakh kg. Then the whole earth- moon system will collapse due to gravitational pull by this living surasa. If that really happened, then there would not have been a earth or atleast moon at this time. But none of that happened. So it is unrealistic.

Comment: @Rickross Ok if even ord Hanuman had 8 siddhis by which he can become big or small as much he wants. But is it mentioned anywhere that Lord Hanuman can regenerate tissues?

Comment: your mathematics is fine I  so I am not in a position to explain the flag you raised but your point is acceptable

Comment: you may consider reading what siddhis mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siddhi

Comment: an understanding of what siddhis are/were may help you understand how the physics of expansion of body or the mouth worked and it did not affected the planetary system.If hanuman had siddhi's then even the demons had siddhi's which they used on man power to dominate in those days and it was not possible for human beings to fight with those powers that was the whole purpose of appearance of all Gods on earth.To have an understanding of Siddhi's I mentioned Neem Karoli Baba and his stories because he had demonstrated in Kaliyug a professor from harvard Richard Alpart was the closest devotee to

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64167/discussion-between-kawin-m-and-user327509).

Comment: Professor Richard Alpart now known as Ramdas is still alive and has seen Neem Karoli baba if you can contact him you may reach a correct answer In my opinion https://jdgoswami.wordpress.com/2015/10/15/story-teller-the-hippie-who-traveled-to-spiritual-creativity/

Comment: To comment on your answer 50 reputation is required hence I am unable to comment on your answer but the incident you mentioned in your answer as did not happen that version of story is wrong the link from which you quoted users are not knowledgeable enough to answer the question correctly and an in complete answer with a vague discussion has been accepted as answer on the link you mentioned.There was a TV serial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z7FVrL6DXdw which had a very big viewership at 4:12 this incident is portrayed and there are many Ramayana like Adhyatm Ramayn, Adbhut Ramayan,

Comment: RadheShyam Ramayana, Valmiki Ramayana, Tulisdas Ramayan http://www.bhagavatam-katha.com/ramayana-story-hanuman-and-the-pearl-necklace-of-mother-sita/

Comment: http://nkbashram.org/community/nkbashram-blog/hanuman-chalisa-verses-and-commentary/

Comment: usually the users who really have knowledge about your question and can convince you to your understanding will not be found on stack exchange or internet websites, they would be sitting some where in some ashram waiting for questions like these to answer them happily 1)http://www.maharajji.com/By-His-Grace/maharaj-ji-appears-as-hanuman-ji.html

2) http://www.indiatvnews.com/news/india/neem-karoli-baba-facebook-mark-zuckerberg-apple-steve-jobs-54973.html

Answer (score 1):

There is no such incident happened. Link to the answer [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/450/why-is-lord-hanuman-portrayed-as-splitting-his-chest-and-showing-that-lord-rama)

> The chest-tearing story does not seem to actually be there in the Ramayana, which just says this:
>
> Rama presented to Seetha, an excellent string of pearls, furnished with superior gems, shining like a beam of moon-light; two clean and beautiful raiment and lovely ornaments. Looking towards Hanuman the monkey, Seetha, daughter of Janaka, having taken off the pearl-string from her neck, repeatedly caught the glimpse of all the monkeys. Looking at her, Rama who was acquainted with the gesture of another, spoke to Seetha as follows: "Dear Seetha! Give the pearl-necklace to a person, with whom you are pleased and in whom the following viz. sharpness, firmness, renown, dexterity, competence, modesty, prudence, virility, prowess and intelligence are ever present." The black-eyed Seetha gave that pearl necklace to Hanuman. Hanuman, the foremost among the monkeys, by wearing that necklace, which was as white as a heap of moonlight-beams, shone brilliantly as a mountain silvered by a white cloud.
> So it looks like Hanuman just accepts the necklace. Now it's possible that that the chest-tearing story is described in some Purana or other scripture, but so far I haven't found any.